# Django can not get permission from group immediately

Tags: django, python-3.x

I find that user can not get the permissions from group.To do that i have to get the user instance again.

I use **Python 3.4.3** and **Django 1.8**

Here is my code using console:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

>>> peter = User.objects.create_user('peter', 'peter@example.com', 'peter')

>>> permission = Permission.objects.get(codename='add_user')

>>> admin = Group(name='admin')
>>> admin.save()
>>> admin.permissions.add(permission)

>>> peter.get_all_permissions()
set()
>>> peter.groups.add(admin)
>>> peter.get_all_permissions()
set()

>>> peter = User.objects.get(username='peter')
>>> peter.get_all_permissions()
{'auth.add_user'}
```

I want to know why and is there any way to refresh the permission from group?

Comment: what do you mean by getting permission from group? do you mean `peter.refresh_from_db()` to refresh the object?

Comment: @AhmedHosny,Thanks for comment.But use ```peter.refresh_from_db()``` still can not get the permission witch has assigned to ```admin``` group from ```peter``` immediately.

Comment: Try peter.refresh_from_db(fields=['groups'])

Comment: @AhmedHosny.I have tried but it still not fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`create_user` saves a user model to the database and returns that same model. If you change that user's permissions, the change is reflected in the database but not on the cached model you've got in your shell. You have to re-fetch the user from the database for those permission changes to be apparent.

The reason `refresh_from_db` doesn't work is that it only reloads direct fields of the model from the database, not other database-dependent values.

Comment: Thanks! so,what you mean is  re-fetch is the only way? And is there any information about this?

Comment: Check the docs for refresh_from_db here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#refreshing-objects-from-database I don't know any way to get 100% consistent behavior when doing this other than re-fetching since it's more than a simple attribute change.